# How can I avoid JS and use only CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After several test, I haven't been able to do what I want to do with a pure css. How can I obtain the same result like the example below without using a javascript.

Is it possible to do that with a pure css?

Thanks.

[**jsfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ghdzy57w/13/)

```js
var main = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
for(var i = 0; i < main.length; i++) { 
 var height = main[i].childNodes[3].offsetHeight;
 main[i].style.height = height+"px";
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.left-child {
  width: 40%;
  height: 120px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.right-child {
  width: 60%;
  height: 180px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-child">
  </div>  
  <div class="right-child">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left-child">
  </div>
  <div class="right-child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Given that the `.right-child` element's height is hard coded in the CSS anyway, what's the point of setting the parent's height in JS at all? Just set `height: 180px` on `.container` too

Comment: but I want to make the height value of container "auto" .container { height: auto;}, is necessary for what i want to do.

Comment: Why the down-vote on the question tho' ?

Comment: @KingKing  _sometimes it's very tempting to give downvotes anyway once you see the question has already had some downvotes_ , do you think that this is a constructive way of perceiving some questions? Quite 
a bizarre explanation from a person with **40k** rep.

Comment: @ZombieChowder you're not experienced much to feel that truth. ***I've not never done*** something like that. But I believe some others have done 
 and will have been doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` to do that, just add `display: flex;align-items: center;` to `.container`

*and remove the `position: absolute` and `transform translate` stuff and you get a clean CSS*

```css
.container {
  background: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;             /* added property */
  align-items: center;       /* added property */
}
.left-child {
  width: 40%;
  height: 120px;
  background: red;
}

.right-child {
  width: 60%;
  height: 180px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-child">
  </div>  
  <div class="right-child">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left-child">
  </div>
  <div class="right-child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tested this an that work! thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

I added `height` to the `.container` because since the children are positioned absolutely, they are out of the document's flow, meaning it's like `.container` doesn't have a child at all.

As for the `height:100%` for the `.right-child`, well it is so that it takes the height of the nearest relatively positioned element,which is the `.container`

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.left-child {
  width: 40%;
  height: 120px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.right-child {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-child">
  </div>  
  <div class="right-child">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left-child">
  </div>
  <div class="right-child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.left-child {
  margin-top:30px;
  width: 40%;
  height: 120px;
  background: red;
  float:left;
}
.right-child {
  width: 60%;
  height: 180px;
  background: blue;
  float:right;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ghdzy57w/14/

Answer (score 1):

A solution without `position : relative` or `position : absolute`

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.left-child {
  width: 40%;
  height: 120px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.right-child {
  width: 60%;
  height: 180px;
  background: blue;
  display:inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-child">
  </div><!--  
  --><div class="right-child">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left-child">
  </div><!--  
  --><div class="right-child">
  </div>
</div>
```